# SBS2011 / IIS7 / PHP / Exchange 2010 - Can't send emails via PHP

Tags: php, email, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

So I have IIS 7 running on our server - which is running SBS2011 and Exchange 2010 - and i'm trying to send an email using a script - PHPMailer, and i'm fairly confident I have it setup correctly. Here is the error I'm getting from output:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
```

Can people humor me, and suggest solutions? Here's what I've tried, that hasn't worked:

- Setup a receive connector with Anonymous login and no authentication, listening on every available IP, or just the server's IP, or 127.0.0.1.
- Granted relay permission to the NT AUTHORITY/Anonymous Login

Here's the full(ish) log:

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@******> (this is an address hosted by the server)
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<*****> (This is a gmal address, if that is relevant)
SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: *****
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: *****
```

**EDIT:** See selected answer below with a caveat - I had another relay connector listening on the same port that was a catch-all, and it was taking all the mail and throwing it out. I changed the port of the NEW connector, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer I gave a while back in another question about the same thing:

You'll need to setup a relay connector and setup the IP that is going to be relaying mail (in this case the IP of your SBS server itself) to be allowed to relay through that connector. Also make sure to set it to "Externally Secured" in the Authentication tab of the connector.

Follow this guide (I'd quote it here but too many formatting issues), easy enough: http://exchangeserverpro.com/how-to-configure-a-relay-connector-for-exchange-server-2010/

Comment: And here begins why I'm so confused - already read and tried that document - it doesn't work. I've read and re-read the article, and i'm positive i'm following instructions properly.  Same error - no change.

Comment: I'm going to correct my own correction with a caveat - this article IS correct, but the issue on my part was that my default connector and this new connector were listening on the same port, and the default was going first and throwing out the mail. I changed to a different port on the new relay, and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Typically relay connectors are set on a different IP, not necessarily a different port.  You add a 2nd IP to the NIC or a new nic completely, and listen on that IP only.  (and from the article: "You can leave the local network settings as is, or optionally you can use a dedicated IP address for this connector if one has already been allocated to the server. Using dedicated IP addresses for each connector is sometimes required if you need to create connectors with different authentication settings")

Comment: It's only a web-app, only going to ever send mail out, and not going to do it very frequently - maybe 5-6 times a day. Do you think just having a different port is going to be an issue? Or should I go the whole nine and add a new NIC - I mean, it just sent my message no problem to my gmail account.

Comment: If you have any apps that will use it in the future that can't specify a port other than 25, it might be an issue, but I think you'll be just fine in your scenario as is.

Comment: AH, cool, thanks then. Ya, I have full control over my app, and it'll only ever be this one. Thanks for the help!